# Can anyone see my firebase json?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-security

So, recently I've been working with Firebase for an app that I build and I'm thinking if anyone can view my data in json.

For example, anyone can add a /.json to my url and view the contents right?

Like : https://myapplication.firebaseio.com/.json (Dummy URL)

Or is there a way to secure it from other people seeing it?

Correct me if I'm wrong. Sorry if this is a silly question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, anyone can view the contents by accessing that URL. That's why it's imperative to [implement security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/quickstart.html) for your Firebase instance. Even  something as simple as the following would be a good start, which only allows reading and writing from authenticated users.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": auth != null,
    ".write": auth != null
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anid. That worked ! Also I have another question. Since all the data that I'm going to retrieve from Firebase is going to be a asynchronous call I'm having to do $scope.$apply every time in angular  to update the scope. Is there any other way to update scope or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Yes, or use [AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/). If you have another question, please make another post.

Comment: Ok. I will try it. Thanks for your help.